# C++ Linked List that mimics vectors

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm wondering if this code is correctly mimicing the "at" function of a vector using linked lists.  This concept was to teach us linkedlists and I'm not sure if I put the pos++ in the correct spot.  Could someone help me out and tell me what each line is doing so I know how it makes the exit from the while loop?  As of now, it's confusing.  THank you!

Here is pastebin of whole project: http://pastebin.com/wyNQx3GP

Thanks guys

```
 // This returns the countyElectionResults result at a particular point
 // in the list.
 // This is analogous to the at method in the vector class.
 countyElectionResults countyElectionList::at(int place){
    if(head == NULL){
            countyElectionResults * name = NULL;
            return * name;
    }
    else{
            countyElectionResults * current = head;
            int pos = 0;
            while(pos != place && current->getNextResult() != NULL){
                    current = current->getNextResult();
            }
            pos++;
            return * current;
    }
    cout << "Not Found" << endl;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also a bug in the code, at the return statement when if condition is true:

```
countyElectionResults countyElectionList::at(int place){
    if(head == NULL){
            // if head is null, then set name to NULL
            countyElectionResults * name = NULL;
            // This is segmentation fault due to dereferencing name (null)
            return * name;
    }
    else{
            // set the current to list head and pos to 0
            countyElectionResults * current = head;
            int pos = 0;
            // compare pos to place, while these are different
            // and list does not end
            while(pos != place && current->getNextResult() != NULL){
                    // set current to next node
                    current = current->getNextResult();
            }
            pos++;  // this should be inside the loop, incremented when current 
                    // advances
            return * current; 
    }
    cout << "Not Found" << endl;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

No. pos++ should be inside the while loop.

```
while(pos != place && current->getNextResult() != NULL)
{
   current = current->getNextResult();
   pos++;
};
```

Comment: But it still works regardless, for some reason, I'm assuming?  Do you know why?

Comment: That's because of the other condition which says come out of loop when list is over. Without incereasing pos how your pos will become place?

Comment: Not sure which cases it won't work for..just tested it and the whole program compiles and runs fine even in instances where it uses the (at) function?  any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

pos++ should be inside the loop because you must count the positions passed through while looping. If you do not do that then checking for `pos != place` has no actual meaning unless place is zero. It currently works for the numbers and the cases you ran so far. It will not work for all cases.....

EDIT----

And when I say won't work I mean it will give wrong result not that it will not compile or it give a SIGSEV

Comment: Not sure which cases it won't work for..just tested it and the whole program compiles and runs fine even in instances where it uses the (at) function?  any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: You call the (at) function with what parameters and how long is your list?